# cgi script can't write to world writable file under apache

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi, centos7, apache2.4

I'm attempting to create a simple CGI script using CentOS 7, Apache 2.4 and Ruby 2.0.  All tools installed from official packages.

My script, which resides at `/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
begin
    file = File.open("test.log", "a")
    file.puts("foobar")
    file.close
rescue Exception
    puts "pwd: #{`pwd`}"
    puts $!.inspect
end
```

When I load `http://myhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi`, I get the following:

```
pwd: /var/www/cgi-bin
#<Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - test.log>
```

However:

```
[root@host cgi-bin]# ls -l /var/www/cgi-bin
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 153 Jul 10 22:03 env.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 359 Jul 11 00:45 test.cgi
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root   0 Jul 11 00:42 test.log
```

How (and where) can I write data from inside this cgi script if not to a world-writable file in the script's own working directory?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a 1990s style CGI launcher when things like [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) exist. It's highly advisable to avoid CGI entirely because it has profound and scary security implications.

Comment: Those files are owned by `root` and it's probably the case that the user running the CGI script, perhaps your HTTP server default user, is not able to access that directory.

Comment: Using 1990s style CGI because I thought it would be quicker than setting up sinatra and this is a throwaway project.  Literally one page with a single form that, when submitted, needs to have its params logged to a flat file.  Will check the permissions on higher level directories in the path, though.

Comment: As my non-root user I can append to /var/www/cgi-bin/test.log.  httpd runs as "apache" I think.

Comment: Looks like it was SELinux.  "setenforce Permissive" and the script was able to write to the file.

Comment: Sinatra is pretty quick for what it's worth, doubly so because you don't even need Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux was blocking the file writes.  "setenforce Permissive" allowed them to go through.  Edited /etc/sysconfig/selinux and rebooted to make permanent.

Comment: SELinux is always there to ruin your day, it's true.